# selecting distinct value with listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, distinct, listagg

I am using oracle 12c database. I am trying to select distinct value with listagg using subquery method. But i am getting an error "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"".

Here is my code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT nr.sd_id,
            ( select listagg(nr.r_num,' ') within group (ORDER BY Nlssort(nr.r_num, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'))
                  OVER ( PARTITION BY nr.sd_id, nr.rid, nr.rr_id) r_num_group 
                  from (select distinct r_num from sg_nr) )
FROM   sg_nr nr;
```

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT nr.sd_id, listagg(nr.r_num,' ') within group (ORDER BY 
Nlssort(nr.r_num, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI')
OVER ( PARTITION BY nr.sd_id, nr.rid, nr.rr_id) r_num_group FROM  sg_nr nr;
```

Comment: Hi i tried this earlier but the result is not distinct for r_num_group

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a windows clause (`OVER`). just use the `WHERE` clause inside inner subquery as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NR.SD_ID,
                ( SELECT LISTAGG(NR.R_NUM,' ') WITHIN GROUP(
                         ORDER BY NLSSORT( NR.R_NUM, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI')) 
                      FROM (
                        SELECT DISTINCT R_NUM
                          FROM SG_NR NRIN
                         WHERE NRIN.SD_ID = NR.SD_ID
                           AND NRIN.RID = NR.RID
                           AND NRIN.RR_ID = NR.RR_ID)) AS R_NUM_GROUP
  FROM SG_NR NR;
```

The best way to achieve it is by using the sub-query as inner view and join it with main table as follows:

```
SELECT NR.SD_ID, NRIN.R_NUM_GROUP
  FROM SG_NR NR
  JOIN (
    SELECT NRIN.SD_ID, NRIN.RID, NRIN.RR_ID,
           LISTAGG(NRIN.R_NUM, ' ') WITHIN GROUP(
                ORDER BY NLSSORT( NRIN.R_NUM, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI' )
           ) R_NUM_GROUP
      FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT NRIN.R_NUM, NRIN.SD_ID, NRIN.RID, NRIN.RR_ID
               FROM SG_NR NRIN) NRIN
      GROUP BY NRIN.SD_ID, NRIN.RID, NRIN.RR_ID
    ) NRIN ON NRIN.SD_ID = NR.SD_ID
          AND NRIN.RID = NR.RID
          AND NRIN.RR_ID = NR.RR_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

A performance wise perspective could be like this as you are already using same table `SG_NR`. Then using `LISTAGG` function with [MATERIALIZE](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_materialize_sql_hint.htm) hint.

```
WITH NR AS (SELECT /*+MATERIALIZE*/
                  * FROM SG_NR)
SELECT NR.SD_ID, NR2.R_NUM_GROUP
  FROM NR
       INNER JOIN
       (  SELECT NR2.SD_ID,
                 NR2.RID,
                 NR2.RR_ID,
                 LISTAGG (
                    NR2.R_NUM,
                    ' ')
                 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY
                                  NLSSORT (NR2.R_NUM, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'))
                    R_NUM_GROUP
            FROM (  SELECT NR2.R_NUM,
                           NR2.SD_ID,
                           NR2.RID,
                           NR2.RR_ID
                      FROM NR NR2
                  GROUP BY NR2.R_NUM,
                           NR2.SD_ID,
                           NR2.RID,
                           NR2.RR_ID) NR2
        GROUP BY NR2.SD_ID, NR2.RID, NR2.RR_ID) NR2
          ON     NR2.SD_ID = NR.SD_ID
             AND NR2.RID = NR.RID
             AND NR2.RR_ID = NR.RR_ID
```